Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: React Select
Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: React Select,
But when I am importing React-Select
import Select from 'react-select';

It is giving an error,
=> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module.
Here, is my dependency list which I have used in my project.
"dependencies": {
  "@ant-design/icons": "^5.3.7",
  "@coreui/chartjs": "^4.0.0",
  "@coreui/coreui": "^5.0.0",
  "@coreui/icons": "^3.0.1",
  "@coreui/icons-react": "^2.2.1",
  "@coreui/react": "^5.0.0",
  "@coreui/react-chartjs": "^3.0.0",
  "@coreui/utils": "^2.0.2",
  "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
  "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.36",
  "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
  "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
  "@mui/icons-material": "5.10.3",
  "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.170",
  "@mui/material": "^5.15.18",
  "@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.5.0",
  "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
  "@types/react": "latest",
  "@types/react-dom": "latest",
  "antd": "^5.17.2",
  "axios": "^1.6.8",
  "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
  "chart.js": "^4.4.2",
  "classnames": "^2.5.1",
  "core-js": "^3.36.1",
  "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^2.0.25",
  "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
  "react-multiselect-checkbox-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
  "react-multiselect-dropdown-bootstrap": "^1.1.0",
  "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
  "react-select": "^5.8.0",
  "react-table": "^7.8.0",
  "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
  "redux": "5.0.1",
  "simplebar-react": "^3.2.4",
  "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
}

